# Layout xml issue in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

Here is my layout:
[image: layout]

Here is my XML. My layout is good except the red color part. I could not able to bring it into view. There is issue in the alignment. Is there a tool to design the layouts easily? Always facing issue in the alignments compatible to all resolutions and for both portrait and landscape dimensions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/productImageView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="380dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="420dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/product_name"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#fff"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/your_price_tv"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Your Price" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#fff"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/your_price"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout9"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#fff"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/button4"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Retail Price" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayout10"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#fff"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/retail_price"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Button" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                android:layout_width="70dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout2"
                android:background="#c0c0c0"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="Button" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout15"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:background="#c0c0c0"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout11"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:background="#c0c0c0"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Buy Now" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button7"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Gush It" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout12"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dip"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:background="#c0c0c0"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Description" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout13"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dip"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:background="#c0c0c0"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/product_description"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="400dp"
                    android:text="Button" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try to format your xml, it is not very readable as no indentation is right

Comment: I just submitted an edit for indentation. @intrepidkarthi For future reference if you select everything in your xml file (in eclipse) you can then press control+i (windows) for automatic indentation

Comment: you'll have to explain why you surround productImageView with 2 linear layouts, and every single textview with another linearlayout . Also, remove useless elements, like RelativeLayout orientation

Comment: also, your top linearLayout is useless, it contains only one element

Comment: @njzk2 This layout works fine in portrait mode. Just made changes into that to work with Landscape mode.

Comment: @Asok I am using linux. Anyway I will try that

Comment: ctrl-shift-F should do, if you have ADT installed. anyway, your layout is cluttered with useless stuff. you really need to clean it first, it'll be much clearer and easier to see what's wrong.

Comment: `LinearLayout` per [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html): "A Layout that arranges its children in a **single** column or a single row.". Based on what it looks like you want just using `RelativeLayout` and utilizing relational placement (i.e.  `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/theIdOfTheElement"`, etc) you should be good.

Comment: Getting multiple opinions when there is a doubt in layout. I will go with relative layout for this.

Comment: first of all use styles this is messy, second you can use TabeLayout for this one

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a grid like this, I would prefer a [`GridLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html)

You can set view's to specific position [+ width/height] in the `GridLayout` using the [`Spec`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.Spec.html) objects in the `LayoutParam`